# Qt for windows CE

Tags: visual-studio, qt, windows-ce

I have installed Qt for windows CE using this link  http://qt.nokia.com/products/platform/qt-for-windows-ce for visual studio8, I can see Qt tab in VS IDE.

I tried to create new application for QT am getting error that

> "There are no Qt/CE platforms defined. Please add your Qt/CE build in the Tools/Options/Qt/Builds dialog."

How can i define platform??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it explains in the error. Go to tools menu, then options submenu. Select Qt from the tree and then select Builds item. There you will see an Add button. Click it. Write the version and path of your installed Qt. Then you are good to go.

Comment: I have done same thing am not able to add Qt version. In add dialog OK option is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I click **Tools**, select the **"Options…"** menu ***item*** (it is not a submenu), up comes the **"Options"** dialogue box, I see no **"Qt"** entry in the tree.  Fresh never-used-before install of Visual Studio 2008 on Windows XP Pro SP3, with Qt add-in installed and I've tried running it as an Administrator too.

Did I miss something?

In the meantime, I have discovered some notes here:
http://www.sereno-labs.com/qt-4-6-2-installation-procedure-friendlyarm-mini-2440-windows-ce-5-0

The device I'm targeting is not a FriendlyARM, rather a Psion hand-held, but nevertheless, suggests that the bare Qt package lacks any VisualStudio binaries.

Further update…

My aging P4 laptop is busily compiling Qt now, has been for some hours.  I found that for the Psion, I had to edit the setcepaths.bat script to make the call to checksdk.exe consistent with the SDKs actually provided.  Upon doing this, things seem to be working.  If you get an error message regarding a missing header, run:

```
checksdk.exe -list
```

That'll tell you what your SDK is actually called.  You might find then that running:

```
checksdk.exe -sdk "Your SDK with spaces (and ARCH in brackets)" -script tmp.bat
```

**tmp.bat** should produce the needed environment.

Lastly, I hit a compiler error due to some left-over autogenerated files in the Qt build directories.  I'll post up the (Cygwin) command I used to clean up the sources mid-build when I find it.